# Magento how to get subtotal session value in custom module?

Tags: php

I am currenly working on one custom module for magento 1.9.1

I am stuck on getting the session value of the checkouts subtotal.

I know how to get it in a template file but i have to get in in a simple php file.

This is the code that i am tring to get the value:

```
<?PHP
require('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento

Mage::app();
echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getSubtotal(); 
?>
```

It's not returning the value. The module is located in /app/code/local if it is important.

Did i have to make any function or something ?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, try to init session before using Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));. Or look there [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152613/magento-cart-session-data-outside-magento)

Answer (score 3):

This may help you:

```
$totalItemsInCart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount(); //total items in cart
$totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals(); //Total object
$subtotal = round($totals["subtotal"]->getValue()); //Subtotal value
$grandtotal = round($totals["grand_total"]->getValue()); //Grandtotal value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try following code it will work

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal() ?>
```

Comment: NO it's not working... :(

Answer (score 0):

To access the cart subTotal in the script outside Magento you need frontend session.

Try this code it works.( Tested )

```
<?php
require('app/Mage.php'); 
Mage::app();

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getSubtotal(); 
?>
```